# What is the name of this design pattern with "cascading attributes"?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Say I have the following classes:

```py
DO_NOT_OVERRIDE = type() # this dictates if an attribute won't be overridden.

class Parent():
    def __init__(self, a: int = 0, b: int = 0):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Child():
    def __init__(self, parent: Parent, a: int = DO_NOT_OVERRIDE, b: int = DO_NOT_OVERRIDE):
        self.parent = parent
        
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        if self._a is DO_NOT_OVERRIDE:
            return self.parent.a

        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value: int):
        self._a = value


    @property
    def b(self):
        if self._b is DO_NOT_OVERRIDE:
            return self.parent.b

        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value: int):
        self._b = value
```

Now, let's create some objects.

```py
parent_obj = Parent(a = 1, b = 2)
child_obj_1 = Child(parent = parent_obj)
```

`child_obj_1.a` would return `1` and `child_obj_1.b` would return `2`, which are both values from `parent.a` and `parent.b` respectively

But consider another `Child`:

```py
child_obj_2 = Child(parent_obj, a = 20)
```

`child_obj_2.a` would return `20` which is a value set in `child_obj_2`, though child_obj_2.b`would still return`2`since`b` is not "overridden" by the child object.

---

**What is this design pattern?**

Comment: Looks like an overcomplicated mechanism of implementing default values through composition. I would call it an antipattern.

Comment: it's not really "default values", if you were to do `parent_obj.a = 3` then `child_obj_1.a` would return `3` instead of `1`